# Where can I buy DUPLO bulk bricks?

Tags: shopping, duplo

The request seems weird, I'm looking to buy for my 1-year-old some Duplo, but they all come in "dog shapes/windows/humans" etc, with a very small amount of rectangular/square blocks, which is all I want.

The old Basic Blocks (80 pieces) were 80 between rectangular and square pieces, that was all I need.
I can't seem to find a list of pieces of "All-in-One-Box-of-Fun", but the pictures on Lego website don't seem to have many of them.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this? 40 square pieces and 40 rectangular pieces would be a good number, but it seems impossible, unless you go in the 200$ range, which is very excessive!

I'm open to other brands, but the one I bought (36$!) don't stick together, they are completely useless!